# Menu responsive pure css

Tags: html, css

i made a menu responsive but i can't make the ul hides. I have seen a lot of tutorials but i dont know what touch more. 
here i left the html and css.  Many navigation menus (especially responsive ones) are created using a combination of HTML, CSS and Javascript. But  This simple CSS only method have to  demonstrate that Javascript isn't always necessary.

````
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span>   </label>     
         <nav>  
         <ul>
        <li  class="one">
        <a href="episodios.html" >EPISODIOS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="two" >
        <a href="nosotros.html">NOSOTROS</a>
        </li>
        <li  class="three"> 
        <a href="entrevistas.html" >ENTREVISTAS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="four">
        <a href="topicos.html" >TOPICOS</a>
        </li>
         </ul>
        </nav> 

header {
  width: 320px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 3;
}

header ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

          flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li {
  font-family: 'IBMPlexMono';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
}

header ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;

  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  -
          user-select: none;
}

.menu-icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-out;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
}

.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  background-color: #000000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
   transition: all  .2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background-color: #000000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all  .2s ease-out;
  transition: all  .2s ease-out;
  top: -5px;
}```
````

Comment: You might have a look at css media queries

Comment: What's the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media query for responsiveness. For example you can use :

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  // your code goes here
}
```

In this case when the screen size is lower than 768px, the code inside that media block will be applied. In you case you want sth like this :

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  header ul{ display:none;}
}
```

This will not display the ul when the screen size is lower than 699px.